# Facebook Graph API - URL object

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I need to fetch the share counts for about thousands of URLs every 30 minutes from Facebook Graph API. Hence I have the following questions:

1. Do I need to register an Application? What details do I need to submit? If not, do I still need an API token?
2. What are the API limits for this kind of operations?
3. What if I batch requests for about 300 URLs per request? How the requests will be counted?

I am actually in the process of registering my app. I still  need to submit some details. However, the submission form requires me to add some permission and features, like `manage_pages`, `user_events` etc. I actually do not see anything that I might need for now.

Thanks.

Comment: 1. You should, otherwise you might get blocked based on your IP address quite quickly, if you send a large number of requests. 2. Limits are dynamic, and depend on several factors, like what kind of token you use, etc. 3. Every request in a batch still counts as one individual request AFAIK; batch just reduces the number of HTTP calls necessary.

Comment: @CBroe Thanks! I decided to register my application. Please read my updated question.

Comment: You don’t need to submit just for the sake of submitting. If you are not asking for any permissions that need review, then don’t submit.

Comment: @CBroe I think this would count as an answer, although I am still interested in the limits for the app tokens.

Comment: Again, limits are dynamic. Pretty much the only one that FB ever communicated was 600 calls per 600 seconds, but I don’t remember if that was for user or app tokens. But in general it depends on number of calls, processing time they consume, etc. Using user access tokens (for multiple users) wherever possible is a general recommendation to avoid running into limits. Other than that, you might see if you can query the value less frequently maybe, or more evenly “spaced”, like 100 now, next 100 in ten minutes, etc. until the cycle is complete.